Image uploader in Ck Editor 4 can't see loaded image
I am using Ck editor to edit my description field. When I click upload a file, its ok but ckeditor doesn't render image on textarea.
This is my config function that I use in _Layout.cshtml
    <script src="~/template/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> 
    <script>
        function RenderCkEditor(inputId) {
            CKEDITOR.replace(inputId, {
                height: 300,
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Default", new { Area = Areas.admin })',
                filebrowserUploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Default", new { Area = Areas.admin })'
            });
            CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'font';
            var fontsizevariable = '12';
            var fontfamilyvariable = 'Arial';

            CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
                ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
                    elements: {
                        p: function (e) { e.attributes.style = 'font-size:' + fontsizevariable + 'px; font-family:' + fontfamilyvariable + ';'; }
                    }
                });
            });
        } 
    </script>

// Rendering the ck editor its OK.

@section Scripts {
    <script> 
        RenderCkEditor('Corporate_Description');
    </script>
}

I am selecting the image and sending it to server. Everything is OK. After sending it I am returning ab json Object that has url and status.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    var uploadResult = await _fileUpload.Upload(Request.Form.Files[0], "editor", "files");
    if (uploadResult.Succeed)
    {
        var baseUri = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}//{uploadResult.Data}";
        return Json(new { uploaded = true, baseUri });
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Error:" + uploadResult.Message);
    }
}

These are error messages in browser console;
ckeditor.js:21[CKEDITOR] Error code: clipboard-image-handling-disabled.
ckeditor.js:21 [CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_errors.html#clipboard-image-handlin
I am using same codes in a different project it works. I cant figure it out.
I tried different versions of Ck editor but it didn't work.

I changed my return json to this:
return Json(new{uploaded = 1, url = baseUri}); 

Then it worked.
